# Parameter independence of Stanley's "content formula". Why?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

For a cell $\square$ in the Young diagram of a partition $\lambda$, let $h_{\square}$ and $c_{\square}$ denote the [hook length](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/hooks.pdf) and [content](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/hooks.pdf) of $\square$, respectively.

R. Stanley remarked following Theorem 2.2, on page 6 of [Some Combinatorial Properties of Hook Lengths, Contents, and Parts of Partitions](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/papers/hooks.pdf) that:
$$\sum_{n\geq0}x^n\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\prod_{\square\in\lambda}\frac{(t+c_{\square})(v+c_{\square})}{h_{\square}^2}=(1-x)^{-tv}.$$
Something caught my attention:

> **QUESTION.** What is the conceptual or combinatorial reason that the right-hand side of
> $$\sum_{n\geq0}x^n\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\prod_{\square\in\lambda}\frac{a+\pmb{q}c_{\square}+c_{\square}^2}{h_{\square}^2}=(1-x)^{-a}$$
> is independent of $\pmb{q}$?

Comment: Doesn’t transposition cancel out all the terms involving only the first power of the content?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, then $f(x)+f(-x)$ has no odd-power terms (including $x$ term). That doesn't mean $f$ has no $x$ term. Does it?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, transposition shows that the expression has to be invariant under $q \mapsto -q$, but not that it is independent of $q$ altogether.

Comment: The RHS is the exponential generating function for permutations by number of cycles. By equation (4) in the paper, $t$ counts cycles of $\sigma$ while $v$ counts cycles of $\sigma^{-1}$, but those are the same so you just get powers of $tv$.

Comment: @lambda: It is not clear if you're answering the question or just remarking.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I guess it's up to you whether you think it answers the question or not, but I left it as a comment and not an answer because I assumed not. It's a combinatorial/conceptual explanation of why the *first* formula depends only on $tv$, but doesn't readily re-express itself in terms of $q$ and $a$.

Comment: @lambda Sorry to respond to your question with a question, but does this invariance (i.e. the independence with respect to $q$) lead to a characterization of the *content* statistic ?

Comment: @InesInstitoris I'm not entirely sure why you're asking me specifically, but I don't see an obvious reason you'd get such a characterization.